# CTE in subQuery

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, common-table-expression

I have a scenario to display data from 2 tables combined. First table Named 'DayTable' consists of daily plan and actual. Second table named 'MonthTable' consists of Monthly plan and actual. I need to display last 6months data and the current month daily data. So i wrote the query like below i for the expected output

```
 Declare @startdate date = CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(dd, -DAY(DATEADD(MONTH, 0, GETDATE())) + 1, DATEADD(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()))) 
 Declare @endDate date = DATEADD(DAY, -DAY(DATEADD(MONTH, 1, GETDATE())), DATEADD(MONTH, 1, GETDATE()))

CREATE TABLE #TEMP
(
 PlanDate NVARCHAR(100),
 [PastTrend - Plan] INT,
 [PastTrend - Actual] INT,
 [Current - Plan] INT,
 [Current - Actual] INT,
)

;With cte
as
(
    Select @startdate sDate
    Union All
    Select DATEADD(day,1,sDate) From cte where DATEADD(day,1,sDate) <= @endDate
)
INSERT INTO #TEMP
SELECT 
REPLACE(CONVERT(CHAR(6), A.sDate, 106),' ',' - ') PlanDate 
,NULL AS [PastTrend - Plan]
,NULL AS [PastTrend - Actual]
,SUM(B.PlanQuantity) AS [Current - Plan]
,SUM(B.Actual) AS [Current - Actual]
FROM cte A 
LEFT OUTER JOIN DayTable B 
ON A.sDate = CONVERT(DATE,B.PlanDate) 
GROUP BY A.sDate 
--ORDER BY A.sDate


SELECT
*

FROM
(
SELECT 
CONVERT(CHAR(3), datename(month,PlanMonth)) + ' ' + RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), YEAR(PlanMonth)), 2)  AS PlanDate
,SUM(PlanQuantity) AS [PastTrend - Plan]
,SUM(Actual) AS [PastTrend - Actual]
,NULL AS [Current - Plan]
,NULL AS [Current - Actual]
FROM 
MonthTable 
WHERE CONVERT(DATE, PlanMonth) >= CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(dd, -DAY(DATEADD(MONTH, 0, GETDATE())) + 1, DATEADD(MONTH, -6, GETDATE())))
group by PlanMonth 


UNION ALL

SELECT 
PlanDate
,[PastTrend - Plan]
,[PastTrend - Actual]
,[Current - Plan]
,[Current - Actual]
FROM 
#TEMP

) T1


 DROP TABLE #TEMP
```

My Output is like

[image: Output Image]

Now i am thining to avoid temp table concept because if any failure after create temp table it will not drop. So rewrite the query like below

```
 Declare @startdate date = CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(dd, -DAY(DATEADD(MONTH, 0, GETDATE())) + 1, DATEADD(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()))) 
 Declare @endDate date = DATEADD(DAY, -DAY(DATEADD(MONTH, 1, GETDATE())), DATEADD(MONTH, 1, GETDATE()))

;With cte
as
(
    Select @startdate sDate
    Union All
    Select DATEADD(day,1,sDate) From cte where DATEADD(day,1,sDate) <= @endDate
)
SELECT 
A.sDate AS OriginalDate
,REPLACE(CONVERT(CHAR(6), A.sDate, 106),' ',' - ') PlanDate 
,NULL AS [PastTrend - Plan]
,NULL AS [PastTrend - Actual]
,SUM(B.PlanQuantity) AS [Current - Plan]
,SUM(B.Actual) AS [Current - Actual]
FROM cte A 
LEFT OUTER JOIN DayTable B 
ON A.sDate = CONVERT(DATE,B.PlanDate) 
GROUP BY A.sDate 

UNION ALL

SELECT 
PlanMonth AS OriginalDate
,CONVERT(CHAR(3), datename(month,PlanMonth)) + ' ' + RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), YEAR(PlanMonth)), 2)  AS PlanDate
,SUM(PlanQuantity) AS [PastTrend - Plan]
,SUM(Actual) AS [PastTrend - Actual]
,NULL AS [Current - Plan]
,NULL AS [Current - Actual]
FROM 
MonthTable 
WHERE CONVERT(DATE, PlanMonth) >= CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(dd, -DAY(DATEADD(MONTH, 0, GETDATE())) + 1, DATEADD(MONTH, -6, GETDATE())))
group by PlanMonth 

ORDER BY OriginalDate
```

But here i have problem. In the output i dont need OriginalDate. How to avoid this. For this i can wrap the union output to a select query but how can i got error in cte. Please guid me. Also suggest which method is best one

Comment: Why don't you just include `IF EXISTS .... DROP` for the temp table? You can also consider a `TRY..CATCH` logic to drop the temp table in case of failures

Comment: ya good idea. but i am trying to avoid temp table. I dont know which method is good. I think direct method is easy and good. Also like this, i have other procedures also using temp. So thinking to avoid it . Thats all. If temp table is the better approach i can go like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finished the query. ACtually i just wrap the query as outer with out the cte. Cte must be the top in the query. The final query is

```
    Declare @startdate date = CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(dd, -DAY(DATEADD(MONTH, 0, GETDATE())) + 1, DATEADD(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()))) 
     Declare @endDate date = DATEADD(DAY, -DAY(DATEADD(MONTH, 1, GETDATE())), DATEADD(MONTH, 1, GETDATE()))



;With cte
    as
    (
        Select @startdate sDate
        Union All
        Select DATEADD(day,1,sDate) From cte where DATEADD(day,1,sDate) <= @endDate
    )
    SELECT
    T1.PlanDate
    ,T1.[PastTrend - Plan]
    ,T1.[PastTrend - Actual]
    ,T1.[Current - Plan]
    ,T1.[Current - Actual]
    FROM
    (
    SELECT 
    A.sDate AS OriginalDate
    ,REPLACE(CONVERT(CHAR(6), A.sDate, 106),' ',' - ') PlanDate 
    ,NULL AS [PastTrend - Plan]
    ,NULL AS [PastTrend - Actual]
    ,SUM(B.PlanQuantity) AS [Current - Plan]
    ,SUM(B.Actual) AS [Current - Actual]
    FROM cte A 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN DayTable B 
    ON A.sDate = CONVERT(DATE,B.PlanDate) 
    GROUP BY A.sDate 

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
    PlanMonth AS OriginalDate
    ,CONVERT(CHAR(3), datename(month,PlanMonth)) + ' ' + RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), YEAR(PlanMonth)), 2)  AS PlanDate
    ,SUM(PlanQuantity) AS [PastTrend - Plan]
    ,SUM(Actual) AS [PastTrend - Actual]
    ,NULL AS [Current - Plan]
    ,NULL AS [Current - Actual]
    FROM 
    MonthTable 
    WHERE CONVERT(DATE, PlanMonth) >= CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(dd, -DAY(DATEADD(MONTH, 0, GETDATE())) + 1, DATEADD(MONTH, -6, GETDATE())))
    group by PlanMonth 
    ) T1 
    ORDER BY T1.OriginalDate
```

But i need to know the peroformance. When i execute this query with actual execution plan Query Cost (Relative to the batch) : 100% 
When i execute the first method using temp the query cost is 90%. Can anyone guid for this